# How to send request from android to servlet with parameters

Tags: java, android, mysql, servlets

I am trying to send a request from my android device to servlet with parameters and parameters are sending as part of the request.

I have a button on clicking on that I get the text from editText views modify my url to make a url with parameters and send that url to AsyncTask.

**Here is my code.**

```
 buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String stringUrl = "http://192.168.11.4:8084/WebApplication1/DemoServlet?email=" + editTextEmail.getText() + "&password=" + editTextPassword.getText() + "&phone=" + editTextPhoneNumber.getText();

            ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                new RegistrationTask().execute(stringUrl);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error!. Please check your internnet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And here is my RegistrationTask code.

```
class RegistrationTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return getResponse(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        editTextEmail.setText(result);
    }

    public String getResponse(String myurl) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String contentAsString = null;
        int len = 500;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(myurl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("Download", "The response is: " + response);
            is = conn.getInputStream();
            // Convert the InputStream into a string
            contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
            return contentAsString;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return contentAsString;
    }

    // Reads an InputStream and converts it to a String.
    public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Reader reader = null;
        reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
        char[] buffer = new char[len];
        reader.read(buffer);
        return new String(buffer);
    }

}
```

I tried to debug my servlet code but request coming as email=password=phone=

Please help me to sort it out.

Comment: take a look to the Apache HttpClient. Very useful for your requirement.

Comment: If you log 'stringUrl' then what do you see? Please format your first code block so we don't have to scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

*Not an answer, but would help you.*

**First** please share the servlet code too

---

**Second**, encode parameter using `URLEncoder.encode(arg:String):String` before sending the request, such as following

```
String stringUrl = "http://192.168.11.4:8084/WebApplication1/DemoServlet?email="
+URLEncoder.encode(editTextEmail.getText())
```

---

Also your method `readIt(stream:InputStream,len:int):String` is not reliable because of the way yo read the info.

Note that `InputStream.read(buf::byte[]):int` would not fill the whole buffer even if too much data is available, and the int response indicates the number of data was written to the buffer, so your code would get data inconsistency.
You may using `DataInputStream.readFully(buff:byte[]):void` which either fills the buffer completely or throws exception when there are not enough data.
Or better way read till EOS, where `read()` method returns -1.